# Is ampicillin a good choice of drug to treat a urinary tract infection caused by E.coli

Tags: pharmacology

Is ampicillin a good choice of drug to treat a urinary tract infection (cystitis) caused by E.coli? How does the environment of the urinary tract effect its ability to treat the bacteria. 
When cultured on a CLED agar plate and an ampicillin disk is placed in the centre it appears to work well, but will it work this well in the human body?

Comment: Hi ! This seems like a homework question. The users of this site will gladly help you, however we will not do your homework for you: it is required that you show your attempts at answering the question first.

Comment: In this instance, the question text should lead you down the right path to the answer: try to summarize the difference between the in vitro antibiotic test (CLED agar) and the in vivo conditions in the urinary tract, and consider the consequences of these differences.